# How do I print my JSON package to my Screen in UE4? Im using bubble code but I am open to switch to C++ if necessary

Tags: c++, json, unreal-engine4

All I want to do is look at what JSON my website is sending to unity when I send a post request to it. I know that it is receiving a package but when I try to print that package to the screen it does not print out the package. The package contains an access token so my script doesn't have to constantly reload and I want to see what that is, for now, to later pull the information and store it. I transferred my bubble code to C++ but the readability is very low. I appreciate any help anyone can give.

````
{
    
    bpv__INT__pf = FTextStringHelper::CreateFromBuffer(
TEXT("NSLOCTEXT(\"\", \"57FF5D494939EDEC637ABB83E369F180\", \"False\")")    );
    bpv__Req__pf = nullptr;
    bCanEverAffectNavigation = false;
}
PRAGMA_ENABLE_OPTIMIZATION
void UTEST_C__pf1010915279::PostLoadSubobjects(FObjectInstancingGraph* OuterInstanceGraph)
{
    Super::PostLoadSubobjects(OuterInstanceGraph);
}
PRAGMA_DISABLE_OPTIMIZATION
void UTEST_C__pf1010915279::__CustomDynamicClassInitialization(UDynamicClass* InDynamicClass)
{
    ensure(0 == InDynamicClass->ReferencedConvertedFields.Num());
    ensure(0 == InDynamicClass->MiscConvertedSubobjects.Num());
    ensure(0 == InDynamicClass->DynamicBindingObjects.Num());
    ensure(0 == InDynamicClass->ComponentTemplates.Num());
    ensure(0 == InDynamicClass->Timelines.Num());
    ensure(0 == InDynamicClass->ComponentClassOverrides.Num());
    ensure(nullptr == InDynamicClass->AnimClassImplementation);
    InDynamicClass->AssembleReferenceTokenStream();
    FConvertedBlueprintsDependencies::FillUsedAssetsInDynamicClass(InDynamicClass, &__StaticDependencies_DirectlyUsedAssets);
}
PRAGMA_ENABLE_OPTIMIZATION
void UTEST_C__pf1010915279::bpf__ExecuteUbergraph_TEST__pf_0(int32 bpp__EntryPoint__pf)
{
    UVaRestSubsystem* bpfv__CallFunc_GetEngineSubsystem_ReturnValue__pf{};
    UVaRestRequestJSON* bpfv__CallFunc_ConstructVaRestRequestExt_ReturnValue__pf{};
    check(bpp__EntryPoint__pf == 8);
    // optimized KCST_UnconditionalGoto
    bpfv__CallFunc_GetEngineSubsystem_ReturnValue__pf = CastChecked<UVaRestSubsystem>(USubsystemBlueprintLibrary::GetEngineSubsystem(UVaRestSubsystem::StaticClass()), ECastCheckedType::NullAllowed);
    if(::IsValid(bpfv__CallFunc_GetEngineSubsystem_ReturnValue__pf))
    {
        bpfv__CallFunc_ConstructVaRestRequestExt_ReturnValue__pf = bpfv__CallFunc_GetEngineSubsystem_ReturnValue__pf->UVaRestSubsystem::ConstructVaRestRequestExt(EVaRestRequestVerb::POST, EVaRestRequestContentType::json);
    }
    bpv__Req__pf = bpfv__CallFunc_ConstructVaRestRequestExt_ReturnValue__pf;
    b0l__K2Node_CreateDelegate_OutputDelegate__pf.BindUFunction(this,FName(TEXT("OnCopleteEvent")));
    if(::IsValid(bpv__Req__pf))
    {
        bpv__Req__pf->OnRequestComplete.AddUnique(b0l__K2Node_CreateDelegate_OutputDelegate__pf);
    }
    if(::IsValid(bpv__Req__pf))
    {
        bpv__Req__pf->UVaRestRequestJSON::SetStringRequestContent(FString(TEXT("email=test@gmail.com&password=Test123")));
    }
    if(::IsValid(bpv__Req__pf))
    {
        bpv__Req__pf->ProcessURL(FString(TEXT("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/login")));
    }
    b0l__K2Node_CreateDelegate_OutputDelegate__pf.BindUFunction(this,FName(TEXT("OnCopleteEvent")));
    if(::IsValid(bpv__Req__pf))
    {
        bpv__Req__pf->OnRequestComplete.AddUnique(b0l__K2Node_CreateDelegate_OutputDelegate__pf);
    }
    return; // KCST_GotoReturn
}
void UTEST_C__pf1010915279::bpf__ExecuteUbergraph_TEST__pf_1(int32 bpp__EntryPoint__pf)
{
    check(bpp__EntryPoint__pf == 7);
    return; // KCST_GotoReturn
}
void UTEST_C__pf1010915279::bpf__ReceiveBeginPlay__pf()
{
    bpf__ExecuteUbergraph_TEST__pf_0(8);
}
void UTEST_C__pf1010915279::bpf__OnCopleteEvent__pf(UVaRestRequestJSON* bpp__Request__pf)
{
    b0l__K2Node_CustomEvent_Request__pf = bpp__Request__pf;
    bpf__ExecuteUbergraph_TEST__pf_1(7);
}
PRAGMA_DISABLE_OPTIMIZATION
void UTEST_C__pf1010915279::__StaticDependencies_DirectlyUsedAssets(TArray<FBlueprintDependencyData>& AssetsToLoad)
{
}
PRAGMA_ENABLE_OPTIMIZATION
PRAGMA_DISABLE_OPTIMIZATION
void UTEST_C__pf1010915279::__StaticDependenciesAssets(TArray<FBlueprintDependencyData>& AssetsToLoad)
{
    __StaticDependencies_DirectlyUsedAssets(AssetsToLoad);
    const FCompactBlueprintDependencyData LocCompactBlueprintDependencyData[] =
    {
        {0, FBlueprintDependencyType(false, true, false, false), FBlueprintDependencyType(false, false, false, false)},  //  Class /Script/VaRest.VaRestSubsystem 
        {1, FBlueprintDependencyType(false, true, false, false), FBlueprintDependencyType(false, false, false, false)},  //  DelegateFunction /Script/VaRest.OnRequestComplete__DelegateSignature 
        {2, FBlueprintDependencyType(false, true, false, false), FBlueprintDependencyType(false, false, false, false)},  //  Class /Script/VaRest.VaRestRequestJSON 
        {3, FBlueprintDependencyType(false, true, false, false), FBlueprintDependencyType(false, false, false, false)},  //  Class /Script/Engine.SubsystemBlueprintLibrary 
        {4, FBlueprintDependencyType(true, false, false, false), FBlueprintDependencyType(false, false, false, false)},  //  Class /Script/Engine.ActorComponent 
        {5, FBlueprintDependencyType(true, false, false, false), FBlueprintDependencyType(false, false, false, false)},  //  ScriptStruct /Script/Engine.PointerToUberGraphFrame 
    };
    for(const FCompactBlueprintDependencyData& CompactData : LocCompactBlueprintDependencyData)
    {
        AssetsToLoad.Add(FBlueprintDependencyData(F__NativeDependencies::Get(CompactData.ObjectRefIndex), CompactData));
    }
}
PRAGMA_ENABLE_OPTIMIZATION
struct FRegisterHelper__UTEST_C__pf1010915279
{
    FRegisterHelper__UTEST_C__pf1010915279()
    {
        FConvertedBlueprintsDependencies::Get().RegisterConvertedClass(TEXT("/Game/TEST"), &UTEST_C__pf1010915279::__StaticDependenciesAssets);
    }
    static FRegisterHelper__UTEST_C__pf1010915279 Instance;
};
FRegisterHelper__UTEST_C__pf1010915279 FRegisterHelper__UTEST_C__pf1010915279::Instance;
PRAGMA_ENABLE_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS```
````